# Run a task only when nobody is logged in.

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-scheduler

Ist it possible on windows 10 to run a task only when no user is logged in?

If a new user logs in and the task is still running it should be killed immediately.

Comment: Have you tried task scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, there isn't.

If you don't want to do this programmatically, I suggest having the program run "At Startup" and "On disconnect from user session". Then have a second task that runs "On connection to user session" that will run a batch script to find your process and kill it if it's running. Unfortunately there no way to do this with zero programming (ie writing the batch file).

Keep in mind that a disconnected session is different than the user not being logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Test if a user is logged in before doing your action.

```
rem return error if logged in

quser | find "Console"
if %errorlevel%==0 exit 1
```